# How to use Gnosis Safe as Proxy in Etherscan

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I created a new Gnosis Safe last week and when I go to the page on Etherscan, I can’t mark it as a proxy to interact with it. It has an error about not being able to find the implementation contract. I have an old Gnosis Safe that I am able to do this with. Any idea why it might be different or how to fix it?

Comment: Hey, can you paste the safe address

Comment: @donoso.eth Sure, it’s: 0xd12745b5CA546A408a35e8C77d81Aa0a7526DE7b

Answer (score 0):

I checked [your Safe address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd12745b5CA546A408a35e8C77d81Aa0a7526DE7b) on Etherscan and it's not showing any transactions.

In order for verification to work, we've found that there needs to be at least one incoming or outgoing transaction that shows up on Etherscan.

See: https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/relay-kit#option-1-verify-contract-in-block-explorer

So the simplest solution is to send a small amount of ETH into that Safe and then [try the verification step](https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/relay-kit#option-1-verify-contract-in-block-explorer) again.